# Python send data to an executable passed as parameter in terminal

Tags: python, command-line, parameters, argv

I have a python script which gets 2 parameters from the command line, an executable and a file. After I do some computation I need to pass by stdin the result of this computation to the executable.

1) is this even possible?
2) if so, how can I do this in Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should never use os.system that's a very dangerous and bad habit.

As for your problem, using subprocess you can do the following:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

#do some stuff 
data = do_some_computation_from_file

#prepare your executable using subprocess.Popen
exe = Popen(['your_executable'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

#pass in the computed data to the executable and grap the result
result = exe.communicate(input=data)[0]
```

Comment: I'm assuming that in a similar way I can get the executable's result back in the program?

Comment: In this example you're actually getting back the result in `result`

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. Was still looking at Popen.

Comment: I'm getting this error with the `exe = Popen` line:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stage1.py", line 42, in <module>
    main()
  File "stage1.py", line 25, in main
    exe = Popen(sys.argv[1], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: You must wrap your executable in a list like this:
`exe = Popen([sys.argv[1]], stdout=PIPE ...`

Comment: is your executable in your PATH ? The traceback is telling you that it can't find your executable try `Popen(['cat'], stdin=PIPE ...` to make sure it's about your executable

Comment: Gives me whitespace or newline as result. I'm 100% sure the executable is correct and should give me a number between 0 and 7. Is result gotten from stdout?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27478/discussion-between-chakib-and-rupert-cobbe-warburton)