# reading binary data of an image as command line argument

Tags: c++, image, binary, stdin

I need to read binary data of an image as command line argument.The binary data should not be stored in any file.The data need to be passed as it is as command line arguments.Is it possible to do so??Please help me with this...Thankyou

Comment: Where is the data? Pipe? Memory? Some encoding of command line argument strings?

Comment: Lets start from the other side and ask how you plan to put a bunch of binary data on the command line in the first place?  `foo <giant blob of binary data>`?  Give an example of what you're working with.

Comment: You could uuencode the data...

Comment: I have created a web service which calls my executable file created for image processing whenever it receives an image .I want to pass binary data of the image as command line argument to this executable file. i dont want to to put the binary data in any file since it will create a dependency .The web service is multi threaded.

Comment: @user3344003::encoding of command line arguments

Comment: As @BasileStarynkevitch said you could uuencode or base64 encode the data, although if it is a large amount you may run into limits on command line length.  I'd probably use a pipe or shared memory.  Knowing the platform you plan to run this on would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could invoke the executable and then pass the image as input data which the executable would receive as standard input.

See this answer to see how to pass data in Python: [Python send data to an executable passed as parameter in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775772/python-send-data-to-an-executable-passed-as-parameter-in-terminal)

For C++, check popen (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/popen.html)